# Are there many "lexical universals" like mama/papa - based on similar re-creation?

Tags: etymology, linguistic-universals, origin-of-language, sound-symbolism

Reading the article  *"Where do mama/papa words come from?"* by Larry Trask, linked in [this answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/869/27251) (itself based on Roman Jakobson's 1959 article *‘Why “mama” and “papa”?’*) we see that a condition for such lexical "universals" is their permanent re-recreation based on physiologically universal phonetic reactions.

We might try to identify such reactions and see what lexical forms they produce, by which I don't mean short exclamations, but nouns and verbs.

We shouldn't expect that all sounds produced by all humans in certain circumstances lead to words, as many of them may remain outside language, like the `aaa` sound one could expect from an unfortunate falling person. But *if* such sounds lead to the creation of words, we might expect the words to be as universal as `mama/papa`.

Have such words been identified? - If not truly universal, at least on extraordinarily large areas?

---

I am intrigued for example that the verb "to tickle", which, like `mama/papa`, relates to the practical area of the *most primary linguistic (but also social and physical) interactions between adults and babies*, has a rather similar base in IE languages (`kt/gd`) as in the Turkic languages (`gd/qt/kt/gj`) - more in this [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/45952/27251) and the [answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/45957/27251) thereunder. Similar structure seems present in Mongolian, and (if we believe Google Translate) even [Arabic](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ar&text=tickle&op=translate) and [Hebrew](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=iw&text=tickle&op=translate) (Latinized [here](https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/yiddish_conversion.htm): `לְדַגדֵג` >> `lְdַgdֵg`). And even (to add insult to injury) in Georgian it's `t’ik’t’ik’i` - which looks like `tickle` (itself a metathesis of `kittle`).

Comment: Related, but different question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20421/9781

Comment: ideophones for the same concept likely have some correlation cross-linguistically. I'd also expect cries of pain, laughter, and surprise to have some similarities although like you say, the extent to which these are linguistic rather than paralinguistic may vary